# CSS - Column alignment between two tables is not possible and the column size is the same

Tags: html, css

I have two tables and the size of the columns is the same between the tables, but on the screen the columns are not aligned. The column's vertical bar is, for some unknown reason, a few pixels to the left or right. I've tried many CSS approaches, but I still don't understand what's missing.

```css
table {
  display: table;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif ;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px 0;
}
th, td {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif ;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px 0;
}
.val { 
  text-align: right
  padding: 6px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:   150px;
}
.bigTotal_bkp {
  display: table;
  border:  1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background:  SeaGreen;
  color:       #FFF ;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:     6px 0;
}
.bigTotal {
  display: table;
  border:  1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background:  SeaGreen;
  color:       #FFF ;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:     6px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Report</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="bigTotal_bkp">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="5" style="width: 350px;">TOTAL Sales onlie storages (without_bkp)</td>
         <td class="val" style="width: 76px;">16124 </td>
         <td style="width: 76px;"> </td>
         <td style="width: 76px;"> </td>
         <td style="width: 300px; color: yellow; background=white;text-align: center">( * _bkp = storages used 10% )</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="bigTotal">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3" style="width: 350px;">TOTAL Sales offline storages</td>
         <td class="val" style="width: 76px;"></td>
         <td class="val" style="width: 76px;">23602 </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Your problem is actualy on small screen or large as  well ? Because on chrome large screen it seems to be fine

Comment: why do you use two tables? you will get perfect alignment when you use only one.

Comment: I'm trying in different OS/Browsers/Resolution, and currently it's not align in Linux/Chrome/Full HD.

Answer (score 1):

```css
    table {
  display: table;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif ;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px 0;
}
th, td {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif ;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 6px 0;
}
.val { 
  text-align: right
  padding: 6px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:   150px;
}
.bigTotal_bkp {
  display: table;
  border:  1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background:  SeaGreen;
  color:       #FFF ;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:     6px 0;
}
.bigTotal {
  display: table;
  border:  1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background:  SeaGreen;
  color:       #FFF ;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:     6px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Report</title>
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="bigTotal_bkp">
      <tr>
         <td style="width: 350px;">TOTAL Sales onlie storages (without_bkp)</td>
         <td class="val" style="width: 76px;">16124 </td>
         <td style="width: 76px;"> </td>
         <td style="width: 76px;"> </td>
         <td style="width: 300px; color: yellow; background=white;text-align: center">( * _bkp = storages used 10% )</td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
         <td colspan="3" style="width: 350px;">TOTAL Sales offline storages</td>
         <td class="val" style="width: 76px;"></td>
         <td class="val" style="width: 76px;">23602 </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot add the two tables in one, because in the real world all pages are files generated by xlstproc. I can't rewrite all the xslt files. The topics are in different tables, they must be aligned.